# jQuery hide validation errors on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that shows additional fields based on what the selected option is.

When the form is validated (with error), an error message appears under the additional field that has been shown. That's the expected behaviour.

If I then select a different option, the old option input hides (expected) but the old validation error message remains.

How can I hide the validation error message?

Form code:

```
<div class="row">
  <section class="col col-12">
    <label class="label">Type</label>
<label class="select">
      <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="" selected>Select a cancelation type</option>
        <option value="c1">Cancel and keep all payments</option>
        <option value="c2">Cancel and issue deposit refund</option>
        <option value="c3">Cancel and issue partial refund</option>
        <option value="c4">Cancel and issue full refund</option>
        <option value="c5">Cancel and add aditional charges</option>
      </select>
      <i></i>
    </label>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="ammount">
<div class="row">
<section class="col col-12">
  <label id="ammountt" class="label" style="display:none;">Refund ammount</label>
  <label class="input" id="ammountl" style="display:none;>
    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-gbp"></i>
    <input class="" id="ammount" type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" placeholder="" name="ammount" value="" >
  </label>
  <label id="aditionalt" class="label" style="display:none;">Aditional charge ammount</label>
  <label class="input" id="aditionall" style="display:none;>
    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-gbp"></i>
    <input class="" id="aditional" type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" placeholder="" name="aditional" value="" ></label>
  </section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#type").change(function () {
    var choice = jQuery(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == 'c3') {
        $('#ammountt').show();
        $('#ammountl').show();
    } else {
        $('#ammountt').hide();
        $('#ammountl').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'c5') {
        $('#aditionalt').show();
        $('#aditionall').show();
    } else {
        $('#aditionalt').hide();
        $('#aditionall').hide();
    }
});


var $CancelBookingForm = $("#cancel-booking-form").validate({

    // Rules for form validation
    rules : {
        name : {
            required : true
        },
        ammount : {
            required: true
        },
        aditional : {
            required: true
        },
    },

    // Messages for form validation
    messages : {
        name : {
            required : 'Please select an upsell from the drop down.'
        },
        ammount : {
            required: 'Please enter a refund ammount.'
        },
        aditional : {
            required: 'Please enter an aditional charge ammount.'
        },
    },

    // Do not change code below
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
});

})
```

Comment: what is the html for the error messages?

Comment: The html that is added by the js is: <em for="aditional" class="invalid">Please enter an aditional charge ammount.</em>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the `invalid` class and then remove it

```
$("#type").change(function () {
    var choice = jQuery(this).val();
    //if you just want to remove them all
    $(".input em.invalid").remove();

    if ($(this).val() == 'c3') {
        $('#ammountt,#ammountl').show();
    } else {
        $('#ammountt,#ammountl').hide();
        $('#ammountt,#ammount1').siblings("em.invalid").remove();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'c5') {
        $('#aditionalt,#aditionall').show();
    } else {
        $('#aditionalt,#aditionall').hide();
        $('#aditionalt,#aditionall').siblings("em.invalid").remove();
    }
});
```